# Add two collections together, merging if present, adding if not

Tags: java, collections, merge

When adding two TVShows together, assuming they are the same show, if TVShow `one` has a Season `1` and TVShow `two` has a Season `1`, it will not merge the `episodes` from Season `1` in TVShow `two` to Season `1` in TVShow `one` as it thinks they are equal. However this issue is that if I also added the episodes in the equals function of Season, then TVShow one would contain two entries, both being Season 1 rather than merging the episodes from two to one.

Is TreeSet the correct collection for this? 
And how should I go about doing this?

```java
public class TVShow extends Show implements Iterable<Season> {
    private final TreeSet<Season> seasons;
}

public class Season implements Iterable<Episode>, Comparable<Season> {
    private final TreeSet<Episode> episodes;
    private String name = null;
    private int number;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this)
            return true;
        else if (!(o instanceof Season))
            return false;
        else {
            Season other = (Season) o;
            return this.number == other.number;
        }
    }
}

public class Episode implements Comparable<Episode> {
    private String name;
    private int number;
}
```

For example:

```java
TVShow one = new TVShow();
Season s1 = new Season(1);
s1.add(new Episode(1));
one.add(s1);

TVShow two = new TVShow();
Season sOne = new Season(1);
sOne.add(new Episode(1));
sOne.add(new Episode(2));
sOne.add(new Episode(3));
two.add(sOne);

one.add(two);
```

Result:
one = {seasons{1, episodes{1, 2, 3}}}

Comment: " I want to add all the episodes" You cannot add `Episode` instances to `TreeSet<Season>`. You will need a `TreeSet<Epsiode>` insetad to do this. But why do you want to? If you just add a `Season` to a `TVShow`, then each `Episode` to a `Season`, this organized much more logically.

Comment: Well if you looked at my code snippet, you could see that each TVShow contains a collection of Seasons, and each Season contains a collection of Episodes

Comment: So what's the problem? You cannot add Episodes to a collection of Seasons.

Comment: "If a TVShow already contains a Season that has the same season number, I want to add all the episodes that are different to the season, else just add the season to the collection in TVShow." Let me rephrase. I don't understand what this sentence means. At first, I thought you mean that you want to add Episodes direcdtly to a TVShow, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Can you illustrate with an example in order to clarify?

Comment: Yes sorry for the confusion. I have added an example to show what I mean, I'll also edit that to re-phrase it too :)

Comment: The examples you give still don't clarify what you are asking. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve? What do you want to do?

Comment: I have edited to re-explain, sorry it's quite a difficult question to explain

Comment: @Code-Apprentice should make sense now, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merging 2 seasons is simple enough, since the `episodes` field is a `Set`, you just call `addAll()` and any duplicates are ignored.

Merging 2 shows is more complex, because when a duplicate season is found, they need to be merged, so you can't just call `addAll()`, since that will add new seasons, but won't merge existing seasons.

The problem is that `TreeSet` doesn't have a method for getting the existing season by `number`. One way to fix that is it change the `Set` to a `Map`, keyed by `number`. That would be the *recommended* way, but there is a trick using `subSet()` and `first()` for getting the object in the `Set` that "equals" the object being looked up.

So, to complete the code, eliminating the `name` fields and the `Iterable` interfaces, as they are immaterial to the question, we get:

```java
final class TVShow {
    private final TreeSet<Season> seasons = new TreeSet<>();

    public TVShow(Season... seasons) {
        this.seasons.addAll(Arrays.asList(seasons));
    }
    public void merge(TVShow that) {
        for (Season season : that.seasons) {
            // Add if season is new, otherwise merge it
            if (! this.seasons.add(season)) {
                this.seasons.subSet(season, true, season, true)
                            .first().merge(season);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.seasons.toString();
    }
}
```

```java
final class Season implements Comparable<Season> {
    private final int number;
    private final TreeSet<Episode> episodes = new TreeSet<>();

    public Season(int number, Episode... episodes) {
        this.number = number;
        this.episodes.addAll(Arrays.asList(episodes));
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Season that) {
        return Integer.compare(this.number, that.number);
    }
    public void merge(Season that) {
        // Just add missing episodes
        this.episodes.addAll(that.episodes);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.number + ": " + this.episodes;
    }
}
```

```java
final class Episode implements Comparable<Episode> {
    private final int number;

    public Episode(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Episode that) {
        return Integer.compare(this.number, that.number);
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(this.number);
    }
}
```

*Test*

```java
TVShow show1 = new TVShow(
        new Season(1, new Episode(1), new Episode(2), new Episode(3)),
        new Season(2, new Episode(1), new Episode(2), new Episode(3)));
TVShow show2 = new TVShow(
        new Season(1, new Episode(2), new Episode(4), new Episode(6)),
        new Season(3, new Episode(1), new Episode(2), new Episode(4)));
System.out.println("show1: " + show1);
System.out.println("show2: " + show2);
System.out.println();

show1.merge(show2);
System.out.println("show1: " + show1);
System.out.println("show2: " + show2);
```

*Output*

```
show1: [1: [1, 2, 3], 2: [1, 2, 3]]
show2: [1: [2, 4, 6], 3: [1, 2, 4]]

show1: [1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6], 2: [1, 2, 3], 3: [1, 2, 4]]
show2: [1: [2, 4, 6], 3: [1, 2, 4]]
```

Output shows that `show2` is unmodified, and that in `show1`, season 1 was merged and season 3 was added.

---

**UPDATE:** Alternate version using `Map` instead of `Set`. *Recommended!*

```java
final class TVShow {
    private final TreeMap<Integer, Season> seasons = new TreeMap<>();

    public TVShow(Season... seasons) {
        for (Season season : seasons)
            this.seasons.put(season.getNumber(), season);
    }
    public TVShow merge(TVShow that) {
        for (Season season : that.seasons.values())
            this.seasons.merge(season.getNumber(), season, Season::merge);
        return this;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.seasons.values().toString();
    }
}
```

```java
final class Season {
    private final int number;
    private final TreeMap<Integer, Episode> episodes = new TreeMap<>();

    public Season(int number, Episode... episodes) {
        this.number = number;
        for (Episode episode : episodes)
            this.episodes.put(episode.getNumber(), episode);
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }
    public Season merge(Season that) {
        for (Episode episode : that.episodes.values())
            this.episodes.merge(episode.getNumber(), episode, Episode::merge);
        return this;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.number + ": " + this.episodes.values();
    }
}
```

```java
final class Episode {
    private final int number;

    public Episode(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return this.number;
    }
    public Episode merge(Episode that) {
        // Nothing to merge
        return this;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(this.number);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thank you very much! As you have said there is a recommended way to do this using a map, how would this be done?

Comment: @ConorEgan Change `TreeSet<Season> seasons` to `TreeMap<Integer, Season> seasons`, where the key is the `number` from the `Season` object. Then `Season` doesn't need to be `Comparable` anymore. --- A similar change can be applied to `episodes` field.